# React-Complete AJAX Request before Rendering Dom... with callbacks

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, reactjs

I looked around on here and I saw a few helpful answers, but nothing that has helped my problem. my relevant code:

[image]
Essentially my idea is to have the onSuccess be a callback function, so that I can finish updating state before i call the child component GameBoard with these props... any idea how to fix this without messing with the async attribute?

Comment: Please post your actual code, not a picture of it

Comment: Have you looked at [Redux](https://github.com/reactjs/redux) with [ReduxPromise](https://github.com/acdlite/redux-promise) middlewhere?

Answer (score 0):

Inside of `render()` you'll want to return an intermediate loading message (or spinner component) that conditionally renders based on a flag. Have your ajax request toggle that flag when finished.

A very basic example...

```
render() {
  if (!this.state.didFetch) return <div>loading...</div>;
  return <GameBoard />;
}
```

Once your ajax request updates state, the render() method will automatically be called again, rendering GameBoard with the props. For more information, check out the component lifecycle documentation — specifically, the section about updating... ["An update can be caused by changes to props or state"](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#updating)

As a side note, it's generally considered bad practice to use jQuery with React due to React's concept of a virtual DOM. And if you're not using jQuery elsewhere, you might want to consider [replacing it completely with axios](https://github.com/mzabriskie/axios).